# How to create this ListBox ItemTemplate in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listbox, styles, datatemplate, itemtemplate

I have a ListBox that contains a simple ItemTemplate with a Grid. And I'm trying to create something like this for every Item received by a Binding in the ListBox:
[image]

I have no experience designing with WPF and I don't know which is the best practice to do something like this, avoiding the text deforming of the Grid sited inside of the rectangle.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to add the blue background.

Put a blue rectangle in the DataTemplate and set ColumnSpan = 4.  This causes the rectangle to fill all four columns.  Apply a SkewTransform to the rectangle to transform the sides.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource='{Binding}'>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Margin='30,6' >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
          <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width='Auto' />
          <ColumnDefinition Width='Auto' />
          <ColumnDefinition Width='Auto' />
          <ColumnDefinition Width='Auto' />

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill='LightBlue'
                    Grid.ColumnSpan='4' 
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                   adiusX="6" Grid.RowSpan="2" RadiusY="5" >
          <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform AngleX="-21.464"/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform X="-9.069"/>
            </TransformGroup>
          </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Text='{Binding Property1}'
                    Grid.Column='0'
                    Margin='10'
                    MinWidth='60' />
        <TextBlock Text='{Binding Property2}'
                    Grid.Column='1'
                    Margin='10'
                    MinWidth='60' />
        <TextBlock Text='{Binding Property3}'
                    Grid.Column='2'
                    Margin='10'
                    MinWidth='60' />
        <TextBlock Text='{Binding Property4}'
                    Grid.Column='3'
                    Margin='10'
                    MinWidth='60' />

      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Screenshot**

[image: ListBox Template]

Comment: You might want to edit your question and just ask about the template,  (instead of three diverse questions). Otherwise the question might be closed.